# How to deal with a changing document structure?

Tags: database, google-cloud-firestore, nosql

Let's assume we initially had the following document structure:

```
// Structure A
car: {
  weight: 1000kg
}
```

Now, for whatever reason, we thought it would be more logical to structure the document like this instead:

```
// Structure B
car: {
  characteristics: {
    weight: 1000kg
  }
}
```

All clients of `v1.0.0` still expect `Structure A`, which was the structure during its development. The updated client `v2.0.0` expects `Structure B`. How do I make sure that everyone can still access the data?

So far I see two possibilities: 
1: The client `v2.0.0` updates documents with `Structure A` to `Structure B` whenever they are read. This means I will end up with a database in which unread documents still have `Structure A` and read ones already have `Structure B`. This doesn't sound so great overall!

2: I upgrade all documents at once on the server-side and then force the user to upgrade its client to make sure that he can still access the documents.

3: ?

Are there any best practices for this or articles about this topic?

Comment: The Firebase Realtime Database and Cloud Firestore are two separate databases. Please only mark your question with the relevant tag, not with both.

Comment: I think the most direct option is the second. Do you agree?

Answer (score 0):

I believe that the best option is the second, which is the most direct.